# How to increase content width for WooCommerce content?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My WordPress https://floridapsychics.org/
The content width 1200px works for all elements for all common WP content type.

My WooCommerce shop https://floridapsychics.org/shop
For all WooCommerce content types such as shop listing, categories and product the content width is being calculated and restricted to 1064px

I'm using WP 2023 child theme. I've set the content area for site and templates to be 1200px from the theme editor. For some reason I can't set the content area for woocomemrce shop, category and product pages. It is calculating the width which comes out to be 1064px even though I've set the content width to be 1200px for all woocommerce pages from theme editor.

How do I set it to 1200px like the rest of my pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width is deduced by some left and right padding settings.
I am not familiar to WP 2023 child theme, but please look for theme settings related to left/right padding or spacing.

Comment: I don't think this is do to with child theme as all templates are working fine except woocommerce so there is something in woocommerce which is calculating the width and adding padding/margin.

Comment: You're right, it's WooCommerce default style. See if you can add an extra CSS `.woocommerce-page main { max-width: none }` to undo that.